# Zendesk REST API Url for articles returning data in Browser, but giving unauthorized error in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, rest, zendesk, zendesk-api

> I am working with ZENDESK Rest API. All the API URLS are returning me
>   expected result in my development environment visual studio, But
>   exceptionally there is one API URL provided by Zendesk which gives me
>   always Unauthorize Error, while the same URL returns data in Browser. 
>   I have mentioned the URL follows

https://YourDomain/api/v2/help_center/articles.json

> Request to zendesk API is as follows:
>   [image]
>
> Response  from zendesk API is asl follows :
>
> [image]
>
> A frequent help will be much appreciated.
>
> Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your Help Center is not active, you may receive that error.  Can you confirm that the Help Center is active?  Can you also share the URLs you've tried which do work?  For example, can you load https://yourdomain.zendesk.com/api/v2/help_center/categories.json ?

Comment: Hi Jimmy,
The help center is active. The url https://yourdomain.zendesk.com/api/v2/help_center/categories.json  returns the json result if run on browser, but again in my visual studio it returns the same Unauthorized error.

Comment: mzh, are you logging the request headers from visual studio?  Zendesk's unauthorized error normally means that the password is incorrect.  Are you using password or API token?  And have you confirmed that the corresponding API authentication method has been activated in your Zendesk at https://yourdomain.zendesk.com/agent/admin/api?  Loading in browser will use cookies for auth which does not need to be enabled, but the other methods do.

Comment: I am using password for authentication. The user has administrator rights on zendesk. And the same user,password are working fine for all other APIs like (Ticket,user). But only the apis related to Helpcenter giving me the same error.

Comment: does /categories.json return results from VS? and any update on the request logs?  Knowing the exact request being sent to Zendesk would help troubleshoot

Comment: No, the categories.json is giving the same unauthorized error. To see the detail request and response, I have updated the question with screenshots.